# what is meaning of hook that used in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, hook

I couldn't understand the exact meaning of Hook in python, tensorflow

```
_LearningRateSetterHook(tf.train.SessionRun**Hook**):
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you explain it to me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This could be a more general question about what hooks are.

Hooks are named appropriately in that they allow a way to 'hook into' certain points of the execution of a program.  Thus you could trigger a function or logging after a certain part of the code executes.

To give an example I have listed the description of the SessionRunHook that you mentioned along with a link to its documentation.  It specifically allows you to 'hook' into the mentioned points.

SessionRunHooks are useful to track training, report progress, request early
stopping and more. SessionRunHooks use the observer pattern and notify at the
following points:

- when a session starts being used
- before a call to the `session.run()`
- after a call to the `session.run()`
- when the session closed

A SessionRunHook encapsulates a piece of reusable/composable computation that
can piggyback a call to `MonitoredSession.run()`. A hook can add any
ops-or-tensor/feeds to the run call, and when the run call finishes with success
gets the outputs it requested. Hooks are allowed to add ops to the graph in
`hook.begin()`. The graph is finalized after the `begin()` method is called.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py