# What will be the equivalent of torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_pre_hook(hook) of pytorch in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I have found `MonitoredSession.run()` as a solution. But I can use it at the time when I am training. `torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_pre_hook` can be integrated with the model. So when the forward is called it automatically called and execute. How I can do this in tensorflow?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136774/what-is-meaning-of-hook-that-used-in-tensorflow) answer your question?

Comment: Actually torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_pre_hook  can integrated with the model. So when the forward is called it automatically called and execute. I am finding such a thing that can work like that in tensorflow. But I can't do this with the answer you given.